# Ассемблер - Работа со светодиодами

Tags: алгоритм, ассемблер, avr

У меня проблема с небольшим заданием, условие (МК AVR):

> Начать работу когда нажимается кнопка К - PB2 - зажжется светодиод на
> выходе PD3 и после задержки (2с) PD4. При нажатии кнопки PB3
> светодиоды погаснут и программа возвращается в исходное состояние.
> Реализация на ассемблере)

Я не очень силен в ассемблере, прошу хотя бы направить на меня на путь истинный, как это должно быть реализовано.

Comment: А контроллер мы будем угадывать?

Comment: Ой, контроллер AVR)

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема-то? Вы бы, может, хоть что-то рассказали-показали о своих попытках. А то непонятно, толи Вы предлагаете нам в угадайку играть, толи задание за Вас выполнить.

Comment: Уже решил проблему, не понимал как правильно алгоритм построить, сейчас запишу решение, может другим полезно будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Теперь перейдем к решению.**

Для начала:

```
cbi ddrb, 2 // сбросить бит и подготовить PB2 к вводу
sbi portb, 2
cbi ddrb, 3 // сбросить бит и подготовить PB3 к вводу
sbi portb, 3

sbi DDRb, 3 // порт PD3 на выход
sbi DDRb, 4 // порт PD4 на выход
```

На самом деле первым делом нужно декомпозировать задачу.
Сначала мы решим то, что ожидания начала(нажатия кнопки) и зажжения светодиодов нам нужно вынести в отдельный цикл. Он будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
loop1:
    sbic pinb, 2 // ожидания нажатия
    rjmp loop1

    sbi PORTD,3 // записать 1 в порт PD3 на выход
    call Delay
    call Delay
    sbi PORTD,4 // Записать 1 в порт PD4 на выход

    rjmp loop2
```

Как мы видим наш цикл заканчивается "rjmp loop2" благодаря чему мы переходим в другой цикл, в котором мы соответственно ожидаем нажатия для погасания светодиодов и возвращение в исходную позицию(на начало первого цикла):

```
loop2:
    sbic pinb, 3 // ожидания нажатия
    rjmp loop2

    cbi PORTD, 3
    cbi PORTD, 4

    rjmp loop1
```

Так же мы можем заметить что у нас стоит условие задержки, это я реализовал в таком виде:

```
Delay: // Задержка
    ldi b, 255 
    ldi c, 255
    ldi d, 10

    PDelay:
        dec b // Перейти в PDelay если b не = 0
    brne PDelay
        dec c
    brne PDelay
        dec c
    brne PDelay
    ret // Выйти с Delay
```

Comment: Не знаю возможностей Вашего контроллера, но все же на будущее пара комментариев. -1. Для организации таких интервалов лучше использовать встроенный таймер, а не такую функцию Delay, как у Вас. На время работы функции все замирает, в более сложной задаче это может навредить. -2. По той же причине не стоит ждать в цикле появления сигнала на входе. Делайте один общий цикл. Считывайте в нем входы, проверяйте. В зависимости от состояния входов и состояния программы выполняйте нужные действия и идите дальше. Небольшой совет: почитайте про конечные автоматы. Может пригодится для таких задач.

Comment: Ну, а для данной учебной задачи - нормальное решение :)

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, я сейчас только пытаюсь понять принцип работы, алгоритм составить у меня проблем нет а вот реализация - вопрос. Будем двигаться вперед =)